# Veracrypt - Error while Permanently Decrypting a non System Disk

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

I'm praying to the lord on high somebody may be able to help me.

I'm trying to permanently decrypt a non-system disk. The drive is an external 5TB connected via USB.

During the decryption process, I received the following error at around 17% completion:

**"Access is denied. Source: volTransformThreadFunction:2754".**

I am unable to mount the drive or seemingly access any of the data on it, and resuming the process gives the same error.

I have only ever used the drive as storage. It was encrypted when new, and has been used as such ever since.

Things I have tried to resolve the issue, in no particular order:

Updated to the latest version of Veracrypt 1.26.7.

- Disabled all ransomware protection, Windows Defender protection in
  general, and my Anti Virus software. Resuming the decryption process,
  both from the same and different computers. Enabled 'Extended disk
  control code support' in the Veracrypt settings.

This disk is massively important to me. I don't have a backup, ironically I was only decrypting as I was in the process of trying to create one, so I really am stuck at the moment.

I don't know where to go from here, so anything you guys can suggest would be really appreciated.